# Convert json into XML in windows forms Applications

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, dotnet-httpclient

In Windows forms, I need to connect to a json file and convert it to an xml file.

I have tried this:

```
string json = @"{
 '?xml': { '@version': '1.0', '@standalone': 'no' }, 'root': { 'person': [ { '@id': '1', 'name': 'Alan', 'url': 'http://www.google.com' }, { '@id': '2', 'name': 'Louis', 'url': 'http://www.yahoo.com' } ] } }"; 

XmlDocument doc = (XmlDocument)JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json);
```

But it is not converting, its still showing json view.

Comment: _"its still showing json view"_ - what?